# How to manager multiple components in CD

Tags: continuous-deployment

We have a use-case where we have multiple components which get deployed. Most of the components are independent of each other and can have there own CD pipelines. But some of the component are dependent and is there any best practice to handle these situations. 
My use case is that I have a API service which can be deployed independently. Now there is a front end application which consumes that API. There is a new change in both the API and front end application. Hence they need to be deployed togather and if required rolled back togather. How to define the CD process for such changes. Are there some best practices or ways to handle such situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following strategy. Let's suppose you need to develop and deploy a new feature that requires changes in the service and in the frontend.

You develop the feature in the service first in a backward compatible way. It means that you can add a new API, but not introduce any breaking change. Then you deploy that backend service using your CD pipeline.

Then you develop the feature in the frontend component. At this stage you may test it against your production service. Then you can deploy your frontend using your CD pipeline.

Following this flow you can continuously deploy any feature in your components.